# Backgroundworker/Control.BeginInvoke() freezing UI

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, begininvoke

I have some code which executes a windows svc (another process) and updates the UI at the same time. The calls use `BeginInvoke`, like so:

```
Install.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { Install.Enabled = false; });
```

This is in the `DoWork` event handler. However, the UI still freezes up. Do I need a call to `Application.DoEvents` somewhere (if so, where?)? How can I eliminate the freezing?

In the button click, I have:

```
GetPrinterDto(DirectoriesTreeView.SelectedNode.Text);

InstallBackgoundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

`InstallBackgroundWorker` just runs the code which updates the UI etc.

What I am trying to do is call a WCF server (hosted in a windows service - this is fine), but while that is off doing its thing, update the progress bar and a label with arbitrary values in an async fashion. When I select a treenode, the event handler for selected treenode is f ired, which may cause some of the slowdown. I will try putting this in its own backgroundworker.

Comment: Can you post some more of the code? Something is blocking your UI and, from the above, it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: What is the UI thread doing at the time? What is `Install`? It *looks* like it should be okay...

Answer (score 4):

While you certainly *could* place the call to update the UI (which is what your call to `BeginInvoke` is doing) in the `DoWork` method, you shouldn't, otherwise, you really wouldn't need the `BackgroundWorker` class.

Rather, you would call the [`ReportProgress` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) which would then fire the [`ProgressChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx).

It's in the event handler of the `ProgressChanged` event that you would make the call to `Install.Enabled = false`.

Comment: So in the event I can update all the UI controls? Is this the actual fix?

Comment: @blade33: Yes, the purpose of the `ProgressChanged` event is to make a call in the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) that is required for the call to succeed; in this case, the UI thread.

Comment: Also, do I need Invoke/BeginInvoke in the progresschanged event? Either way, I still get lag.

Comment: I know that when selecting a treeview node (which is required before clicking the button), there are about 10-15 lines (setting variables but not going across the network etc). Maybe this needs its own background worker too?

Comment: @blade33: No, you do not need to call `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` in the `ProgressChanged` event; the `ProgressChanged` event will be called on the UI thread.  If you are getting lag, it's because you are either updating the UI thread too frequently, or the operations that you are calling the (result of setting `Enabled` to `true` on the `Install` instance) are taking too long (I can't say, I don't know if you have anything bound to that `Enabled` flag).

Comment: @blade33: If there is extra information about what you are doing pertaining to the question, you should update the question with that information.

Comment: See above. Thanks. BTW, the UI was probably being updated too frequently. I will try to spread that out. Instlal is just a button, so that shouldn't cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not directly related to the use of `BeginInvoke`. It probably has more to do with how much it is being called. You could use `ReportProgress` in conjunction with the `ProgressChanged` event, but assuming you replace all of your `BeginInvoke` calls with `ReportProgress` then you may wind up with similar problems because `BackgroundWorker` will automatically marshal the event handlers on the UI thread using the same mechanisms that `BeginInvoke`/`Invoke` are using anyway. I would say the quick solution is to reduce the frequency at which you are attempting to update the UI.

Personally, I think the use of `BeginInvoke` to update the UI with worker thread progress is *way* overused. And in the same regard the `BackgroundWorker` class promotes this suboptimal method as well. It is usually better to have the worker thread publish update information periodically to a shared data structure and then the UI thread can pick it up on its own schedule (usually by polling using a `Timer`). This has several advantages:

- It breaks the tight coupling between the UI and worker threads that the `Control.Invoke\Control.BeginInvoke` imposes.
- It puts the responsibility of updating the UI thread on the UI thread where it should belong anyway.
- The UI thread gets to dictate when and how often the update should take place.
- There is no risk of the UI message pump being overrun as would be the case with the marshaling techniques initiated by the worker thread.
- The worker thread does not have to wait for an acknowledgement that the update was performed before proceeding with its next steps (ie. you get more throughput on both the UI and worker threads).

It is unfortunate that `BackgroundWorker` lacks the necessary mechanisms for using this alternate approach. However, you *should* be okay with using `ReportProgress` as long as you do not call it too frequently.

Comment: The problem still remains (I've reduced the UI updates). The code in the windows svc is WMI, is this part of the problem?